# The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ReadContactsActivity>, String, int)

Tags: android

I am using the toast inside `onPostExecute(Boolean result)` method.Here is the code for it

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    //objAdapter = new listAdapter(ReadContactsActivity.this, items);
    //listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
    dialog.dismiss();
    if(result)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   

}
```

I am getting error "The method `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)` in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments   `(Class<ReadContactsActivity>, String, int)`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For display Toast Use following code.

```
   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    //objAdapter = new listAdapter(ReadContactsActivity.this, items);
    //listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
    dialog.dismiss();
    if(result)
        Toast.makeText(Yourclassname.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(Yourclassname.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Downvoting! onPostExecute itself is called on UI Thread.Above answer is totally wrong, don't know how OP has accepted it?

Comment: There is no need to right postExecute code in runOnUiThread, as Vipul Shah said it already runs at UI Thread. You just need to change is:
Toast.makeText(Yourclassname.this, "text", 1500).show();

Comment: @VipulShah: Sir i am new in this technology will you explain me how it can be done in runOnUiThread.

Comment: @Supreet as vipul and MuhammadAamirALi said we not need to use runOnUiThread in postexecute() method. Sorry for my mistake and thanks.